# How to delete slicer cache specific to one worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that clears the pivot table slicer cache in my workbook. I have two pivot tables in the workbook and i'd like to modify the code to clear the slicers only on a specific worksheet. Does anyone know how I can modify to do this?

```
Dim cache As SlicerCache
For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    If cache.FilterCleared = False Then cache.ClearManualFilter
Next cache
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction

```
Sub test()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cache As Slicer

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    For Each cache In pt.Slicers
        cache.SlicerCache.ClearAllFilters
    Next cache
Next pt

End Sub
```